# Insert random VALUE into Mysql table

Tags: mysql

How can I turn the "X" of this sql code into a random `VARCHAR` which has to be 10 chars long?

```
INSERT INTO mybb_invitecodes
(`code`, `used`, `maxuses`, `expire`, `primarygroup`, `othergroups`, `createdby`) 
VALUES('X', '0', '1', '0', '2', '8', '1');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
INSERT INTO mybb_invitecodes
(code, used, maxuses, expire, primarygroup, othergroups, createdby) 
VALUES (LEFT(UUID(), 10), 0, 1, 0, 2, 8, 1);
```

And simply use numeric values without quotes like:

```
VALUES ('X', 10, 0, 1, 0, 2, 8, 1)
```